# Blackberry Android push registration issue

Tags: android, blackberry, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have followed the step which is given in  [Android Runtime for Blackberry](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html). But I didn't get registration ID in GCMIntentService.

I have checked my logcat and found below warning
SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE for GCMRegister.

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Did u solve this issue? I am also facing similar issue in BB.